# How to add array to new key of existing Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

here is my full function, it is from a React-Native project using redux and making a ajax call with axios and redux-thunk:

```
export function FetchEtiquetas() {

  return function (dispatch) {
      axios.get( url )
        .then(response => {

          response.data.map( record =>
            {

            axios.get('https://e.dgyd.com.ar/wp-json/wp/v2/media?_embed&parent='+record.id)

              .then(response => {
                // compose the new json string with each post gallery
                let data_json = '[';
                response.data.map( record =>
                  data_json = data_json + '{ "title": "' + record.title.rendered + '", "subtitle": "'+ record.caption.rendered.slice(3, -5) + '", "illustration": "' + record.source_url + '"},'
                );
                data_json = data_json.slice(0, -1)+"]"; // removes last comma

                record.gallery = date_json;
                console.log("date_json record.gallery: "+record.gallery);

              })
              .catch(error => {
                  console.log(error.response)
              });


            console.log("gallery in data action: "+record.gallery);
          }

          );

          dispatch({ type: FETCH_ETIQUETAS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })

        }
      );
  }
}
```

In the map function, this is the record format:

```
{
  id: 521,
  date: "2014-04-16T16:24:04",
  date_gmt: "2014-04-16T16:24:04",
  modified: "2018-01-12T23:58:22"
}
```

and this is the data_json format once it completed:

```
[
 { "title": "img6", "subtitle": "", "illustration": "domain.com/img6.jpg"},
 { "title": "img7", "subtitle": "", "illustration": "domain.com/img7.jpg"},
 { "title": "img8", "subtitle": "", "illustration": "domain.com/img8.jpg"}
]
```

How can I add data_json to each record?

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you've possibly got something asynchronous going on, and you're possibly assigning or logging things before they're available... you'll need to post some more code/context.  It's also a little unclear as to what might be JSON strings and what might be actual JavaScript objects in your snippets.

Comment: I'd suggest you read what JSON actually is.  Hint, it's a text interchange format.  What you are showing in your first code block is a Javascript object or sometimes called a Javascript literal.  That is not JSON.

Comment: let me update my question to give more context

Comment: @JamesThorpe you are right. I just updated the code so you can see the async part.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it by updating the asignment to:

```
record.gallery = JSON.parse(data_json);
```

It was a simple change but I figured it out thanks to what was pointed out in the comments:

> The original object is not a JSON object, but a plain javascript
>   object.